# jQuery Selector after id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i cant figure out the correct selector for a table.

```
  <tr id="test1">
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="2">\*SELECT THIS \*</td>
  </tr>
```

I want to select tr with id and chose the input of of the 2nd tr "*SELECT THIS*"

```
$("#test1").next()
```

So i'm inside the 2nd tr, but i want the td under this tr.

`$("#test1").next().$("td")` is not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#test1").next().children('td');
```

From the sibling, you then need to delve into its children. More concise would be:

```
$('#test1 + tr td');
```

Answer (score 3):

Close! Use `.children();`

```
$("#test1").next().children('td');
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$("#test1").next().find('td');
```